# Background request with delegate in iOS

Tags: ios

In my app i am uploading image(to AWS S3 server) in background with delegates. I do not want to wait till it reaches delegates callback methods. So after 1 second I go back to previous screen with
    [popToViewController:myPreviosuScreenController].

Problem is when request is complete it doesn't find the delegates. And throws error.
How to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the request's delegate an object that doesn't get deallocated when you pop the view controller.